# how to show same column data one time as a parent in array

Tags: php, laravel, associative-array

```php
array:2 [
  0 => {
    "id": 5
    "module_name": "Directory"
    "parent": "Core Tools"
  }
  1 => {
    "id": 7
    "module_name": "Tasks"
    "parent": "Core Tools"
  }
]
```

But I want like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core Tools
    (
        [0] => Directory
        [1] => Tasks
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use collect group by

```php
$arr = json_decode($your_json, true);
collect($arr)->groupBy('parent')->toarray();
```

Comment: Tsaikoga then how i show that from foreach

Comment: @AneesSiddique just loop it. because it has been converted to array. `->toarray()`